# How to build a react button that stores the selection in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a list of buttons with values that are stored in a state and user is only allowed to use 1 item (I dont want to use radio input because I want to have more control over styling it).

```js
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const items = [
  { id: 1, text: "Easy and Fast" },
  { id: 2, text: "Easy and Cheap" },
  { id: 3, text: "Cheap and Fast" }
];

const App = () => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState([]);

  const clickTask = (item) => {
    setTask([...task, item.id]);
    console.log(task);
    // how can I make sure only 1 item is added to task
    // and remove the other items
    // only one option is selectable all the time
  };

  const chosenTask = (item) => {
    if (task.find((v) => v.id === item.id)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <label>
            <button
              type="button"
              className={chosenTask(item) ? "chosen" : ""}
              onClick={() => clickTask(item)}
              onChange={() => clickTask(item)}
            />
            <span>{item.text}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-cvhivt?file=/src/App.js

I am trying to only allow 1 item to be added to the state at all the time, but I dont know how to do this?

Example output is to have `Easy and Fast` in task state and is selected. If user click on `Easy and Cheap`, select that one and store in task state and remove `Easy and Fast`. Only 1 item can be in the task state.

Comment: Question seems to be a bit unclear to me. Are you trying to hold only the selected task in the task state? Can you provide an example of the expected output

Comment: Yes, only 1 item can be selected and only 1 item should be in the task state

Comment: If you could provide more context on what you are trying to do overall. I think people may be able to help you better.

Comment: I am trying to build something like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/3563906-Good-Cheap-Fast) but only allow 1 option to be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const items = [
  { id: 1, text: "Easy and Fast" },
  { id: 2, text: "Easy and Cheap" },
  { id: 3, text: "Cheap and Fast" }
];

const App = () => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState();

  const clickTask = (item) => {
    setTask(item);
    console.log(task);
    // how can I make sure only 1 item is added to task
    // and remove the other items
    // only one option is selectable all the time
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <label>
            <button
              type="button"
              className={item.id === task?.id ? "chosen" : ""}
              onClick={() => clickTask(item)}
              onChange={() => clickTask(item)}
            />
            <span>{item.text}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: yes, I think i over complicated stuff by using array. One thing I noticed is that selection is always behind one click? [here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-r68iv4?file=/src/App.js) where I click number 1 but because number 2 was selected before console log shows the old one?

Comment: Oh that is because state updates are not reflected immediately so your console.log will always show the previous state

Answer (score 0):

Think of your array as a configuration structure. If you add in `active` props initialised to `false`, and then pass that into the component you can initialise state with it.

For each task (button) you pass down the id, and active state, along with the text and the handler, and then let the handler in the parent extract the id from the clicked button, and update your state: as you `map` over the previous state set each task's active prop to true/false depending on whether its id matches the clicked button's id.

For each button you can style it based on whether the active prop is true or false.

If you then need to find the active task use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate it in the state tasks array.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Tasks({ config }) {

  const [ tasks, setTasks ] = useState(config);

  function handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    setTasks(prev => {

      // task.id === +id will return either true or false
      return prev.map(task => {
        return { ...task, active: task.id === +id };
      });
    });
  }

  // Find the active task, and return its text
  function findSelectedItem() {
    const found = tasks.find(task => task.active)
    if (found) return found.text;
    return 'No active task';
  }

  return (
    <section>
      {tasks.map(task => {
        return (
          <Task
            key={task.id}
            taskid={task.id}
            active={task.active}
            text={task.text}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          />
        );
      })};
      <p>Selected task is: {findSelectedItem()}</p>
    </section>
  );

}

function Task(props) {

  const {
    text,
    taskid,
    active,
    handleClick
  } = props;

  // Create a style string using a joined array
  // to be used by the button
  const buttonStyle = [
    'taskButton',
    active && 'active'
  ].join(' ');

  return (
    <button
      data-id={taskid}
      className={buttonStyle}
      type="button"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >{text}
    </button>
  );

}

const taskConfig = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Easy and Fast', active: false },
  { id: 2, text: 'Easy and Cheap', active: false },
  { id: 3, text: 'Cheap and Fast', active: false }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tasks config={taskConfig} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.taskButton { background-color: palegreen; padding: 0.25em 0.4em; }
.taskButton:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 0.25em; } 
.taskButton:hover { background-color: lightgreen; cursor: pointer;  }
.taskButton.active { background-color: skyblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```